# pytest for simple Python class with argparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, argparse

I am looking to write a PyTest for my class `ModeHandler`.

My test is loosely setup like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def mode_handler_fixture():
    return ModeHandler()


@pytest.fixture
def mode_handler():
    mode_handler = ModeHandler()
    return mode_handler


def test_mode(mode_handler):
    assert mode_handler.get_mode() == 'dev'
```

The class looks like this:

```
class ModeHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        parser = ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--mode')
        self.mode = parser.parse_args().mode
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
sudo python -m pytest -s -x -vvv rain/tests/components/test_mode_handler.py
===================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.10, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /private/var/www/rain/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /private/var/www/rain
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                              

rain/tests/components/test_mode_handler.py::test_mode usage: __main__.py [-h] [--mode MODE]
__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -x -vvv rain/tests/components/test_mode_handler.py
ERROR

============================================================================ ERRORS ============================================================================
_________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_mode __________________________________________________________________

    @pytest.fixture
    def mode_handler():
>       mode_handler = ModeHandler()

rain/tests/components/test_mode_handler.py:12: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
rain/components/config/mode_handler.py:11: in __init__
    self.mode = parser.parse_args().mode
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/argparse.py:1827: in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/argparse.py:2581: in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = ArgumentParser(prog='__main__.py', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
status = 2, message = '__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -s -x -vvv rain/tests/components/test_mode_handler.py\n'

    def exit(self, status=0, message=None):
        if message:
            self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
>       _sys.exit(status)
E       SystemExit: 2

/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/argparse.py:2568: SystemExit
=================================================================== short test summary info ====================================================================
ERROR rain/tests/components/test_mode_handler.py::test_mode - SystemExit: 2
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! stopping after 1 failures !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
======================================================================= 1 error in 0.28s =======================================================================
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `parse_args()` with no parameters, it defaults to `sys.argv` which are the same arguments you passed to `pytest`.

So your `ModeHandler` class is initialized it sets up the parser with the single argument `--mode` and then calls `parse_args` it receives `["-s", "-x", "-vvv", "rain/tests/components/test_mode_handler.py"]` as arguments, and is unable to recognize any of them, so it throws an error and exits immediately.

One work around would be to edit `sys.argv` prior to calling the `ModeHandler` class.

For example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mode_handler():
    sys.argv = [program_name, "--mode", "myMode"]
    mode_handler = ModeHandler()
    return mode_handler
```

Or you can use the `parse_known_args()` method instead which doesn't return an error if the parser encounters unrecognized arguments.

for example:

```
class ModeHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        parser = ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--mode')
        self.mode = parser.parse_known_args().mode
```

Or you can do a sort of combination of the two and change the `ModeHandler` class to accept a default `args` parameter in the constructor and pass that to the `parse_args` method.

For example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mode_handler():
    args = [program_name, "--mode", "myMode"]
    mode_handler = ModeHandler(args)
    return mode_handler


class ModeHandler:
    def __init__(self, args=None):
        parser = ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--mode')
        if args is None:
            args = sys.argv[1:]
        self.mode = parser.parse_args(args).mode
```